# adding watermark and showing image on fly ( without saving it on server or replacing the original image )

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

i have a helper function to add watermark to images

(i've made some changes to make the code shorter please ignore minor syntax errors or missing code)

```
function watermark($path_to_img  , $image_name )
{


  $ci = &get_instance();




  $config['source_image']   = $path_to_img.$image_name;;
  $config['new_image']          = $path_to_img.'wtr_'.$image_name;
  $config['wm_type']         = 'overlay';
  $config['wm_overlay_path'] = base_path('/files/transparent_bar.png');
  $config['wm_font_path'] = base_path('application/assets/view/tahomabd.ttf');
  $config['wm_font_size']   = '8';
  $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
  $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
  $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
  $config['quality'] = '100%';  
  $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '0';
  $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '0';

  $ci->image_lib->initialize($config); 
  $ci->image_lib->watermark(); 

}
```

it works fine but it saves the watermarked version on server , i want to show/download it on the fly without saving it on the server or replacing the original image .... i've no idea how can i do this in codeigniter ?

something like :

```
    $img =  watermark($path_to_img  , $image_name);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo  ( $img );
```

Comment: Did you question the efficiency? Generating images on the fly will suck up your server memory and it's bad juju on high traffic sites.

Comment: @NickOpris i know that  , i just have a employer whose short on HDD  (his idea) ... it's a temporary solution until he be able to afford some new hdd for his server , server config is pretty good though

Answer (score 1):

You can still save it in a temp directory and have a code removing images older than a few minutes for example. Or harder, have a php script streaming out the image, e.g. the URL should be something like script.php?IMG=flower.jpg

http://thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml for the second option above

Or
http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/

Answer (score 0):

To replace the source image, set source image path to new image.

```
$config['source_image']   = $path_to_img.$image_name;
$config['new_image']      = $path_to_img.$image_name;
```

Comment: thanks but i've said  `without saving it on server or replacing the original image `

Comment: You mean you dont want to replace the original image? If so, the what are you getting for your code.

Comment: thats exactly what i mean